# Fetching data from the internet after a page opens in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am having some performance issues with my code. I am working with basic MVVM in Xamarin forms project, and I want to fetch data from the internet when someone navigates to another page. Below is what I have done;

This is how I am navigating to another page via Command; (To be honest I don't really know if this method of navigation has some performance penalties)

```
if (Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != typeof(SubcategoryPage))
{
   await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new SubcategoryPage());
}
```

Here, I am passing Id of a particular category to get its corresponding subcategories

```
public SubcategoryPage(int id)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext  = new SubcategoryPageViewModel(id);
}
```

In the constructor of the **SubcategoryPageViewModel**, I used the Id to fetch the data online like so;

```
public SubcategoryPageViewModel(int id)
{
    SubcategoryLoader(id);
}
```

Below is the method that is fetching the data from the internet through my **DataService** class. The code below work well in getting the data from the internet;

```
private async Task SubcategoryLoader(int id)
{
   try
   {
       var subCategories = await SubcategoryDataService.GetSubcategories(id);

       if (subCategories.code == 1) // StatusCode = Successful 
       {
            SubCategories = subCategories.document;
       }
       else
       {
           await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Oops!","Something went wrong", "Ok");
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Oops!", ex.Message, "Ok");
   }
}
```

Now my problem is that the **SubcategoryPage** doesn't open until the online service is over which leads to a serious lags. So what I want to have happen is to open the **SubcategoryPage** before the internet services happen.

Please any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: use the page's `OnAppearing` event to load the data asynchronously

Comment: Thank you for that quick response. i have done that but, imagine i want to navigate to another page say detail page. If i want to exit from the detail page back to the subcategorypage, the onappearing event will fire which will call the online service again. And i don't want that to happen. Do you have any other way?

Comment: use a simple bool flag to prevent the request from running more than once

Comment: What a great suggestion. Thank you @Jason i wish there is another way because i don't really wanna do that.

Comment: In `OnAppearing`, you can check if the list is empty, and then refresh.

Comment: @Shaw Thank you for your answer. But i understand the list you're talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Move it to `OnAppearing` method .
- Add a simple check .

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    if(BindingContext == null)
    {
         BindingContext = new SubcategoryPageViewModel(id);
    }            
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried but it is still the same thing. I don't know if this is caused by the way I am navigating or because I placed method for the online operations in the constructor of the viewmodel

Comment: Could you provide us a basic ,reproducible project  to test?Cause it works fine on my side .